# The return type is incompatible with <Interface.functionName>

Tags: java, return-type, incompatibletypeerror

I get

> "Return type is incompatible with Bar.doClick()"

```
import some.library.Bar

public class Foo implements Bar {

   public enum Outcome {
       ONE, TWO, THREE, NEW;
   }

   public Outcome doClick() {
       return Outcome.NEW;
   }
}
```

Will give me the error, why? I am trying to return the right type I thought.

`Bar.class` contains the following lines:

```
    public enum Outcome {
        ONE, TWO, THREE, NEW;
    }
    Outcome doClick ();
```

I am told by *Eclipse* that if I change

```
public Outcome doClick() {
    return Outcome.NEW;
}
```

into

```
public Bar.Outcome doClick() {
    return Outcome.NEW;
}
```

I can solve the error but create a new one on my return line. I think I am really lost on a principle matter here and could use some foundational understanding.

Comment: You can have less problems if you give the `enum`s different names.

Comment: Please don't add the answer itself into the question statement; you're welcome to answer your own question if you resolve it first, and by accepting Sotirios's answer, you've already in essence marked this question resolved.

Comment: Sotirios did lead me to the right answer so I marked his answer for the point system - but the code in his post didn't immediately describe what my solution was so I posted my solution also. I suppose I will refrain from this in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `Bar` interface, `Outcome` is referring to the `enum` member you declared inside `Bar`. Therefore the `doClick()` abstract method has a return type of `Bar.Outcome`.

In your `Foo` class, you declare another `enum` member also called `Outcome`. The method `doClick` you wrongly declared in `Bar` has a return type of `Foo.Outcome`. Since method signature does not take into account the return type, you effectively have this

```
public Outcome doClick() {
    return Outcome.NEW;
}

public Bar.Outcome doClick() {
    return Outcome.NEW;
}
```

which will cause a compilation error because you have duplicate methods.

Your `doClick()` method has to return a `Bar.Outcome` object to implement (satisfy) the `Bar` interface.

```
public Bar.Outcome doClick() {
    return Bar.Outcome.NEW;
}
```

Because of shadowing

```
return Outcome.NEW;
```

was referring to `Foo.Outcome.NEW` which is not of type `Bar.Outcome` which is the expected return type.

I don't know why you've declared two enums with the same name.

Comment: I was trying to implement an interface that already contains these fields. And it looks like I am able to avoid calling Bar.Outcome doClick() if I delete my second enum declaration. Thanks for the help, this aided my understanding a lot!